# Longitud de un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

> Extender la clase dada para que implemente una función contar() que imprima en consola la cantidad de elementos que contiene la propiedad "valor". (No modificar el constructor dado)
>
> Instanciar la clase y llamar a la nueva función contar().
>
> ```
> // No modificar este constructor.
> function Clase (elem)
> {
>   this.valor = [];
>   this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
>   this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
>   this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
>   this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
> }
> ```

---

Dado ese ejercicio, lo que realicé fue:

```
Clase.prototype.metodo()
{
  var a = this.valor.length;
  return a;
}

var miClase = new Clase(4);

console.log(miClase.metodo())
```

Pero la longitud del array me da 0; no sé en qué me estaría equivocando, ¿dónde está el problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Estás usando `long` como nombre de variable?? Es una palabra reservada en Javascript (y en muchos lenguajes). No lo hagas. Ademas, no tiene sentido llamarla así. Tampoco entiendo cómo quieres construir el array (lo estás llenando como si fuera PHP en lugar de Javascript). Finalmente, la declaracion del "metodo" (otra vez, pesimo nombre para un metodo) está mal.

Comment: El código que compartes incluye un error de sintaxis y no devuelve 0. Corrige los errores y coloca el código que tengas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que `valor` es un objeto te recomiendo contar la cantidad de propiedades de este de la siguiente forma

```js
 function Clase (elem) {
     this.valor = [];
     this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
     this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
     this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
     this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
 }

 Clase.prototype.metodo = function() {
     var a = Object.keys(this.valor).length;
     return a;
 }

 var miClase = new Clase(4);

 console.log(miClase.metodo())
```

Usando `Object.keys(obj)` te devuelve un array con las keys del objeto. Lo cual te permite obtener su `length`

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener en cuenta una cosa: lo que tienes no es un array sino un array asociativo (o un objeto). Es decir, un grupo de parejas clave-valor. Es por eso que `length` no funcionará. Puedes usar un método como el que se explica en esta [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/3695983), contando las claves que hay en el objeto/array asociativo:

```js
// No modificar este constructor.
function Clase (elem)
{
  this.valor = [];
  this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
  this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
  this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
  this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
}

Clase.prototype.metodo = function()
{
   var numElementos = Object.keys(this.valor).length;
   return numElementos;
}

var miClase = new Clase(4);

console.log(miClase.metodo())
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estas agregando los elementos al array, sino que los estas agregando como propiedades del array, y tales propiedades no se contabilizan en el `length`, son propiedades normales de un objeto.

Donde dices

```
this.valor['elem1'] = 1;
this.valor['elem2'] = 2;
this.valor['elem3'] = 3;
this.valor['elem4'] = elem;
```

deberia ser

```
this.push(1);
this.push(2);
this.push(3);
this.push(elem);
```

para que la propiedad `length` de valor, tenga un valor distinto de `0`.

Pero como dice **No modificar el constructor** habra que hacer algo diferente.
Esto depende de la interpretacion de la consigna.

Si se entiende que "la cantidad de elemtos que contiene la propiedad valor" como la cantidad de elementos que tienene el `array` valor o cuandas propiedades tiene el `objeto array`.

En ese caso querer la cantidad de elementos del array, asi como esta esta bien, no requiere cambios.

Si se quiere que `Contar` retrone la cantidad de propiedades puedes hacer:

```
Clase.prototype.Contar = function() {
  return Object.keys(this.valor).length;
}
```

Lo cual cuanta la cantidad de propiedes (no de elementos) del objeto.

salu2